# Magento: Flat Calender in Magento frontend

Tags: magento, datepicker, frontend

How can I add flat calendar datepicker in magento frontend?

```
Calendar.setup({
    flat: 'container',
})
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar.setup takes parameter 'flat' which is the id of the element you want to use to host your flat calendar. So this should work:

```
<div id="calendar--flat"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    Calendar.setup({
        flat: 'calendar--flat',
        ifFormat: '%m/%e/%y',
        align: 'Bl',
        singleClick: true
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Note that if you define the `inputField` or `button` param at the same time this will probably cause an error.